# Triangle strip triangulation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 2d, triangulation

I want to convert the vertices of a triangle strip to independent triangles so I can draw them using OpenGL's `GL_TRIANGLES` primitive type.

However, none of the following two codes works and I cannot understand why:

```
for(int i = 0; i < triangleStripVertices.size() - 2; i++) {
    triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i));
    triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 1));
    triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 2));
}
```

and this one doesn't work either:

```
for(int i = 0; i < triangleStripVertices.size() - 2; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 1) {
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 2));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 1));         
    } else {
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 1));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 2));
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

The broken output looks like:

[image: broken output]

Comment: I expect the second piece of code should work. What is the problem? Have you considered front face counter-clockwise or clockwise?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485034/convert-triangle-strips-to-triangles?rq=1

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am following this tutorial: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Finger-Swipe 
but my triangle strip has a strange behaviour. The first point is also connected with the last one so it's not a strip as expected. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Then, you may have problems other than interpret strips to triangles. Why not just draw triangle strip directly and see what is the result? Then, you could check whether your input triangle strip is correct or not. Also, to simplify, you can reduce the size of your triangle strip and see what happen by drawing it as triangle list.

Comment: I first tried to do it with a triangle strip but it didn't work...Here a picture of my problem that occured with the triangle strip: http://dec.imghost.us/y4oR.png  any idea? I am going crazy...thank you!

Comment: Draw with `glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINES)` for some more insight. But it looks to me like you have the vertex connectivity incorrect, in particular you are missing a few edges like AC and have some new ones like AH. Also an easier test to see if a number is even or odd (rather than using modulo arithmetic) is to perform a bit-wise AND (&) against **0x1**. If true, the number is odd (as bit 1 is the only binary digit that can be an odd number) and the sum of an even number (all other powers of 2) plus an odd number is always odd.

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried a lot of things but I just can't figure out the reason... As I said I am following this tutorial: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Finger-Swipe and everything works great so far except the thing that the front of the arrow (swipe track) is connected with the end of it... it looks like this: http://dec.imghost.us/y6O5.png
My points are calculated the exactly same way as in the tutorial and the order is correct. I am working with andengine by the way but I doubt that the problem is related to the engine. I appreciate your help, any ideas more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close in your attempt, but there's one point you're missing.  Triangle strips have a concept of the "oldest vertex", which is the one that is removed once a triangle is processed.  Because of needing to keep the facedness (sometimes called *vertex winding*) of the triangles the same in the strip, the oldest vertex isn't the next one in the list; it flip-flops between the oldest and second oldest in the list.

For example, let's say you have a list of vertex indices

```
GLuint indices = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

and you call `glDrawElements()` with that list.  The following triangles will be rendered, using the vertex indices from the above list: (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 5).

So, to unwind a triangle strip into a set of triangles, you need to take that into account.  Here's a snippet that will do what you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < triangleStripVertices.size() - 2; i++) {
    if (i % 2) {
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 1));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 2));         
    } 
    else {
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 1));
        triangleVertices.add(triangleStripVertices.get(i + 2));
    }
}
```